# Displaying hours from converting milleseconds isnt displaying right

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I want to get the difference between times who are Calendar object instances. For some reason I am getting a negative number (**-17666324.42**) when using this function.

For overtimeHourLimit I use the value of 8.

```
/*Date*/
Calendar mDateIn = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar mDateOut = Calendar.getInstance();
mDateOut.set(mDateOut.YEAR, mDateOut.MONTH, mDateOut.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDateOut.HOUR_OF_DAY+10, mDateOut.MINUTE+25);

public String getRegHours(float overtimeHourLimit)
{
    DecimalFormat twoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    double totalHours = 0;
    totalHours = (mDateOut.getTimeInMillis() - mDateIn.getTimeInMillis()) / (3.6f * Math.pow(10, 6));
    if (totalHours <= overtimeHourLimit)
        return twoDecimal.format(totalHours);
    else return twoDecimal.format(overtimeHourLimit);
}
```

edit: narrowed it down to the  mDateOut.set() method. @HarshPandey found out when using mDateOut.add() method instead, it adds to the time correctly. However, I am still stumped on why the .set() method didn't work in the first place.

edit2: https://github.com/MienTommy/CalendarTest I pushed out a sample code that should be equivalent to the code snippet in this question. The only difference is that YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH constants aren't static in Android, but it shouldn't make a difference since I initialized them with the same instances.

tl;dr The .set() method isn't working as expected.

Comment: what is the input when you get negative number (-17666324.42)?

Comment: I am using Calendar.getInstance() for dateIn and Calendar.getInstance() then adding 10 hours and 25 minutes for dateOut.

Comment: you are using wronlgy the method of calendar

Comment: BTW, these troublesome old date-time classes have been supplanted by the *java.time* framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem is here:

```
mDateOut.set(mDateOut.YEAR, mDateOut.MONTH, mDateOut.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDateOut.HOUR_OF_DAY + 10,
    mDateOut.MINUTE + 25);
```

for the sake of the explanation:

getTimeInMillis() is getting the epoch: time since 1 January 1970 00:00:00

and this method:

[mDateOut.set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-int-int-int-)()...

Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR_OF_DAY, and MINUTE. in the calendar instance....

but you are passing as parameter the constants of the class Calendar so you are setting the date to a value previous to **1 January 1970 00:00:00**

consider that doing this:

```
mDateOut.set(mDateOut.YEAR, mDateOut.MONTH, mDateOut.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDateOut.HOUR_OF_DAY + 10,
        mDateOut.MINUTE + 25);
```

is the same as doing this....

```
mDateOut.set(1, 2, 5, 21, 37);
```

you can verify that new value by doing:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(mDateOut.getTime()));
```

and you will get as output:

> 0001-03-05 21:37:40

therefore **mDateOut** is actually a date waaaaay back in the past...

and the result negative :)

Comment: Makes sense, so what would be the correct way of using the set() method?

Comment: if you need the actual date then there is no need to use calendar... just create a new instance of java.utl.date and if will get the actual time....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
long seconds = (mDateOut.getTimeInMillis() - mDateIn.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
double totalHours = (int) (seconds / 3600);
```

From our discussion, it seems like

```
mDateOut.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10)
mDateOut.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 25)
```

works fine.

My best guess is that you can use the `set()` method to just set the time, but can't do any complex time calculation in it, and use that to set time. And that calculation is handled perfectly in the `add()` method.

Comment: No luck, same output (-17666324) but the decimals truncated.

Comment: Why are your variable names different. You are creating `dateIn` and `dateOut` but using `mDateOut` and `mDateIn`. Are you passing them around to different methods?

Comment: My bad, I was trying to provide a snippet with only the necessary information. mDateIn and dateIn should be the same as well as mDateOut and dateOut.

Comment: Alright. This whole question has perplexed me. This may not make sense, but try replacing `mDateOut.YEAR`, `mDateOut.MONTH` etc, with `Calendar.YEAR`, `Calendar.MONTH` and so on.

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you please share the full relevant code? I'm really interested in figuring this out.

Comment: I get the same output :( I narrowed the problem down to this line being the error: mDateOut.set(mDateOut.YEAR, mDateOut.MONTH, mDateOut.DATE, mDateOut.HOUR_OF_DAY+10, mDateOut.MINUTE+25);

if I remove that line then I get 0 as the output (which is correct). I also changed the line to this 

mDateOut.set(mDateOut.YEAR, mDateOut.MONTH, mDateOut.DATE, mDateOut.HOUR_OF_DAY+1, mDateOut.MINUTE);

But I get about the same output (-17666........).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117367/discussion-between-harsh-pandey-and-tommy-saechao).

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct. But you are using outmoded classes that make this work confusing and more difficult than necessary.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial. When you do not specify the desired/expected time zone, your JVM’s time zone is implicitly applied. That default may change at any moment. So I suggest you always specify.

## `Instant`

Instead of `.Calendar`, use `ZonedDateTime` when you need a time zone and `Instant` when you need UTC. Generally best to use UTC for most business logic, storage, and data exchange.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant later = … ;
```

## `Duration`

The `Duration` class captures elapsed time in hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( now , later );
Duration overtimeLimit = Duration.ofHours( 8 );
Boolean overtime = ( duration.compareTo( overtimeLimit ) > 0 );
```

## `BigDecimal`

For getting a decimal fraction of hours, I suggest avoiding `double`. As a [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_decimal_point) number, that type trades away accuracy for speed.

Instead, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to avoid erroneous extra digits to the right of your decimal point. The scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. `RoundingMode` determines what kind of rounding approach to take such as “schoolhouse” rounding you were likely taught in elementary school that has a bias towards larger numbers, or [“Bankers rounding”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) ([`HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN)) which is more fair by rounding toward even number when equidistant.

Rather than hard-code magic numbers, use `TimeUnit` to calculate while making your code more self-documenting.

```
int scale = 2 ; // Decimal places to right of decimal point.
BigDecimal minutesInAnHour = BigDecimal.valueOf( TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes( 1 ) , scale ) ;
BigDecimal totalMinutes = BigDecimal.valueOf( duration.toMinutes() , scale ) ; // Calling `toMinutes` truncates any seconds and fractions of second that might be in the duration.
BigDecimal worked = totalMinutes.divide( minutesInAnHour , scale , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ) ;
```